# Why Scala implement andThen function only for Function1

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Why Scala has implementation of method *andThen* only for Function1 (which takes only one parameter). I don't see any reason why rest of functions does not have such method.

Below we have legal code which will compile:

```
val firstFunction: String => String = ???
val secondFunction: String => String = ???
firstFunction.andThen(secondFunction)
```

but this will not compile:

```
val firstFunction: (String,String) => String = ???
val secondFunction: String => String = ???
firstFunction.andThen(secondFunction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would want `andThen` to return a `Function2` in your `firstFunction.andThen(secondFunction)` example.

You can easily add this to `Function2` (or any other `FunctionN`):

```
implicit final
class Function2MulticategoryOps[A,B,C](val f: (A,B) => C) extends AnyVal {

  def andThen[X](g: C => X): (A,B) => X =
    (a,b) => g(f(a,b))
}
```

`tupled` by itself won't help much there: you *also* need something like `untupled`:

```
// note the awful syntax for functions with domain a tuple
implicit final
class Untuple[A,B,C](val f: ((A,B)) => C) extends AnyVal {

  def untupled: (A,B) => C =
    (a,b) => f((a,b))
}
```

As to why the `FunctionN` classes lack these methods, I don't know; surely someone would chime in with something related with *performance*.

**PS** *If you ask me, I think life would be easier if there will be **no** `FunctionN` classes, and functions of several arguments would simply be functions with domain a product type; all this `FunctionN` business is just a convoluted and partial implementation of the representable multicategory coming from a category with products.*

Answer (score 5):

> I don't see any reason why rest of functions does not have such
>   method.

Because it is trivial to transform a `Function2[String, String, String]` to a `Function1[(String, String), String]`, using `Function.tupled`:

```
firstFunction.tupled andThen secondFunction
```

This will work for functions of any arity.

Comment: I guess the OP would want a `Function2`, not a `Function1`.

Comment: @EduardoParejaTobes The OP can have a `Function2` just as described in the answer, but if he wants to compose it with using `andThen`, he's going to have the match the arity.

Comment: I'll write an answer, hard to explain myself in a comment.